# Open internal frame by variable name

Tags: java

How to reference internal frameName to the variable and open it?

```
String frameName = "aaaaaaaa";

frameName fN =new frameName();
MFDesktop.add(frameName);
frameName.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Java doesn't work that way.

Comment: how i can do it

Comment: 1-  i have frameName in table

Comment: Obligatory: take a look at JavaFX instead of using Java Swing. Besides that, you could have a `Map<String, JFrame>` that stores all JFrames in a key-value like storage. Then you can just `map.get("frameName")` to get the instance of the associated frame. Or am I misunderstanding your question?